# How to pass data from closure without repeating yourself

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

I'm using Play 2 with Anorm to manage database access. A common pattern I find myself doing is this:

```
val (futureChecklists, jobsLookup) =
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>

    val futureChecklists = futureChecklistRepository.getAllHavingActiveTemplateAndNonNullNextRunDate()

    val jobsLookup = futureChecklistJobRepository.getAllHavingActiveTemplateAndNonNullNextRunDate()
        .groupBy(_.futureChecklist.id)
        .withDefaultValue(List.empty)

    (futureChecklists, jobsLookup)

  }
```

Which seems kinda weird, because I have to repeat myself. It also gets a bit unruly if I have several variables I'll need in the outer scope, but I don't want to keep the connection open.

Is there an easy way to pass this information back without having to resort to using `var`s?

What I would like is something like:

```
val futureChecklists
val jobsLookup

DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>

  futureChecklists = futureChecklistRepository.getAllHavingActiveTemplateAndNonNullNextRunDate()

  jobsLookup = futureChecklistJobRepository.getAllHavingActiveTemplateAndNonNullNextRunDate()
      .groupBy(_.futureChecklist.id)
      .withDefaultValue(List.empty)

}
```

That way I don't have the same tuple at the beginning and end.

Comment: I think it could be useful if you could show pseudocode of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @TeWu sure, I'll add some

Comment: You can use custom loan pattern. E.g `def withCheckAndJob[T](f: (CheckType, JobType) => T): T = ???`

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no easy way not to duplicate the tuple declaration, but `var` is definitely not the way to go around it.

You're mentioning that it becomes weird and difficult with multiple variables at time which returned as a tuple. This indeed can become really tricky and error prone, especially then you end up having large N-tuples with the same parameter types. In that scenario I would consider having a dedicated contained i.e. a `case class` where you can reference variables by name and not by position in the tuple. The side benefit is that you can assign the whole container to a variable and reference it in the natural way.

Last but not least you don't mention much about your particular use case, but maybe it is worth considering having the 2 queries results obtained in the separate `withConnection` block. If you are using any collection pooling mechanism, then there is hardly any benefit having it in the same with connection block and with the separate blocks you might even get a flexibility to pararelize the DB queries using separate connections.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways that i came up with:

## Return tuple immediately

```
val (users, posts) =
  DB.withConnection { connection => (
    connection.getUsers,
    connection.getPosts
  )}
```

I think this is OK for simple code and small numbers of `val`s. For more complex code and more `val`s this can be error prone. Someone can accidentally change order of elements in tuple on just one side of assignment, and assign data to wrong `val`s (which will be reported by compiler only if it also cause type mismatch).

## Use anonymous class

```
val dbResult =
  DB.withConnection { connection =>
    new {
      val users = connection.getUsers
      val posts = connection.getPosts
    }
  }
```

If you like to have `users` and `posts` variables instead of `dbResult.users` and `dbResult.posts` you can:

```
import dbResult._
```

This solution is a little exotic, but it works just fine and is quite clean.

## Use case class

First define case class for your return value:

```
case class DBResult(users: List[User], posts: List[Post])
```

and then use it:

```
val DBResult(users: List[User], posts: List[Post]) =
  DB.withConnection { connection =>
    DBResult(
              users = connection.getUsers,
              posts = connection.getPosts
            )
  }
```

This is best if you intend to reuse this case class multiple times.

Comment: There more ways than that. PS: Anonymous class is worse than tuple there for me.